# UINavigationBar is smaller on first load; Bigger when navigating backwards

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios13

Note: This only happens in the new card layout for iOS 13 on iPhone X devices and above.

On first load, the `navigationBar` is too small - the bottom line is very close to the `back` button.

If I navigate forward, and then back, the `navigationBar` is the proper size.

I ultimately solved the discrepancy with:

```
            let navbarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navbarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            navbarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
            self.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navbarAppearance
```

I'd still like to know where the difference in sizing is coming from, thanks!

(I can't post screenshots, as the app is proprietary, but happy to clarify further!)